# How to convert an ogv video to an wmv video?

Tags: video, codecs

Is there an application for Ubuntu 12.04 to direcly convert an ogv video exceeding 200 MB into an wmv video possibly with a simple GUI (no terminal, no scripts). Is there such an application for multiple conversions? I tried to employ DivX but I was not able to make a check because the lower part of the DivX window was out of the screen of my netbook. Many thanks in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 4):

If you are happy to use FFmpeg, and yes this is command line not gui, one suggested command line to produce a wmv files that should play on a lot of devices and platforms is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ogv \
       -c:v wmv2 -q:v 4  \
       -c:a wmav2 -b:a 128k \
       output.wmv
```

You can experiment a little with the quality settings for the wmv2 video, decreasing to 2 will get better quality and increasing above this will get progressively lower quality. With the bitrate settings for the wmav2 sound increasing the bitrate may get you better quality sound. All of this depends a lot on the quality of the input audio and video streams.

To run this command on multiple streams you would need to construct a *for* loop and this would be easy enough to demonstrate if you are happy with the suggested encoding syntax.

Answer (score 3):

[WinFF](http://packages.ubuntu.com/WinFF) [image: Install WinFF]
 is a GUI for the command line video converter, FFMPEG. It will convert most any video file that FFmpeg will convert. WinFF does multiple files in multiple formats at one time. You can for example convert mpeg's, flv's, and mov's, all into avi's all at once.

Answer (score 2):

Try the  [Mobile Media Converter](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.php). It will also convert almost any video that FFMPEG supports, plus it can convert almost any video MENCODER supports. It has a really simple GUI.

[image: Mobile Media Converter main window]